# Google analytics js code

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

На сайте есть интеграция с Google Analytics, в таком виде я вижу её в аккаунте: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Саму аналитику на сайт подключал не я, поэтому подозреваю, что она лежит в коде:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>`

Мне нужно добавить коды для отслеживания события клика по кнопкам, но там для инициализации требуется другой скрипт ([ссылка](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=ru)). Если синхронно подключить два скрипта, где я буду видеть отображение событий, или, возможно, нужно сделать по-другому

Comment: есть еще в меню события, но там пусто

Answer (score 2):

Код подключения Google Analytics совсем другой. Проверьте на сайте еще раз, либо подключите заново, [регистрируя сайт](https://analytics.google.com).

Чтобы отследить действия кнопок, Вам нужно создавать "[цели](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=ru)" в панели управления Google Analytics (найдете в вкладке - Администратор).
Далее отчеты о действиях целей можно будет смотреть в вкладке - Отчеты, также в панели управления GA.

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт аналитикса это analytics.js или ga.js (старая версия).
Для настройки целей лучше установите Google Tag Manager - настройка намного удобнее и более гибкая.
А если добавлять отслеживание кликов прямо в код, то используйте код (для новой версии аналитикса) типа:

```
ga('send','event','категория','действия');
```